# How to find final value of proportional constraint

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I have a constraint to set the height of the view.

The constraint is proportional height constraint.

I want to calculate the height using the constraint that's I want to know what is the view height.

any APIs to do that ?

I know I can manually find it myself as well using formula but I don't want to do that

Lets say the height constraint 58% of parent view and it has constant value of 10 then what is the total height assigned by constraint to the view

Comment: Unclear of what you are asking here

Comment: I want to know the height value produced by propotional constraint

Comment: Read the pertinent view's `frame` property after the constraints have been updated. You need to override a method of `UIViewcontroller` to catch that timing I think.

Comment: oh ok .. where should I override ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the view will be:

```
0.58 * parentView.frame.height + 10
```

The height of the parentView isn't established until Auto Layout runs, so if you were to do this calculation, you would do it in an override of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Since you aren't interested in calculating that yourself, you can simply read the final frame height of the view in an override of `viewDidLayoutSubviews` which runs after Auto Layout has applied the constraints.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // read final view size here
    print(myView.frame.height)
}
```

Comment: basically I want to update some UI constraint ... so if I do it in this even ... will it trigger endless cyclic invocations

Comment: What is the constraint you want to update? Perhaps there is a way to write it so that Auto Layout does the work for you.

Comment: basically I have a view which has multiple views inside... based on the visibility of the views inside the the parent view size will be decided. so I want to decide the size ?